# control image size in bootstrap

Tags: django, bootstrap-4

I am using Django I am trying to make image slider using bootstrap, this is my code so far

```
{% extends "blog/modelsbase.html"%}
{% block content%}
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img class="d-block w-100" src= "/media/models/dd08-43fc-ae2b-c6bc75ade6f6.jpg" alt="First slide">
        </div>
          {% for image in images %}
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src= "{{image}}" alt="Second slide">
          </div>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </body>

{% endblock content%}
</html>
```

this is my views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import os
images = os.listdir('/media/models/model1')

def test_model_bt(request):
    return render(request,'blog/model1.html',{'title':'TEST_MODEL','images':images})
```

The images are showing correctly,I would like to place the images inside some sort of container to give them max size [800x800] (if they are larger than it reduce size else `pass`), how can I do it ?

Note:for now my code is "mobile friendly" I would like to keep that

I got my slider from [Carousel · Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way you can do it with [sorl thumbnail](https://github.com/jazzband/sorl-thumbnail) and you can do as follows

```
{% load thumbnail %}
{% thumbnail image "800x800" crop="center" as im %}
{{ im }}
```